# Running python script on EC2 using an android app

Tags: android, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an android app that must execute python code in ec2 on demand. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Does the Android app need to wait for a response from the Python script?

Comment: No, Python script will make run few Mysql queries.. thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step to get started with `Python` as backend and `Android`:

1. Install MAMP, WAMP or LAMP etc on your local computer depending on OS. Install `python` separately if it's not already included.
2. Introduction to Flask and RESTful services : follow https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask.
3. Maintain your code in version control eg `Git`. It is also useful to streamline your code upload from local to server.
4. Get a server : Since you might have to install some modules/packages on your server I recommend to have server with `root` access. You can try `AWS free tier` for 12 months.
5. Install `Apache/Ngnix`, `python`, `SQL`, `phpmyadmin` and `Git` depending on OS you have bought from `AWS` to start serving.
6. Go to your server root (mostly `/var/www/html/`) and `git clone` your project repository and change your environment variables and configuration as per step 5.
7. Ideally you should check here that you are getting expected response for your requests . Use `Postman` to test `post` requests.
8. Now you can consume your web service on `android` using any networking library like [retrofit](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).

Let me know if you need clarity on any point. Happy coding.

Comment: I will try and get back to you if I run into any problems. Thanks :D

Comment: Hey Nitesh, you mentioned to use flask microframework  if it a small application. The python application that I am trying to use does image processing. Is that considered small? Can I use it for this application? Also, can you slightly elaborate how to use the things that you mentioned because I am a newbie. Thanks :D

Comment: Edited my answer. Application size is decided by the scale and features it has. If its only doing image processing it can be considered as small application.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [remote management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/execute-remote-commands.html) tool that amazon provides.

You can have you servers setup with the tools,the ssm agent and the script you need to execute. Then send a remote command to them through the sdk.

Check the related ssm java sdk and how you can utilize it with [android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simplesystemsmanagement/AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.html).

Comment: Thanks !! I will try and revert back if i find any problems :)